# Default Elastic Load Balancer DNS works with Amazon Certificate Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, amazon-elb

I'm trying to request an ssl cert from [Amazon's Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/01/elastic-load-balancing-support-for-aws-certificate-manager/) service and apply it to my ELB, however after entering the default DNS name for my ELB:

```
my-aws-elb-XXXXXXX.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

The request fails without giving any useful error messages. I did see a notice about having sufficient IAM rules. I enabled the Full ACM Manager permission policy for my IAM user however I'm not sure how that links up with making requests from the Amazon web console.

Is it not possible to use the default DNS or do I need my own domain name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to own the domain you are requesting an ACM certificate for. Since you don't own the amazonaws.com domain, you can't request a certificate for that domain.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense. I guess I was hoping some aws magic could handle this scenario... ;-)

Comment: Thanks Mark, also thinking about this situation and hope AWS add the magic :P